# Pine script store one specific candle data in variable

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to store one specific candle of the day, say O=H or O=L in variable and it will be valid until next such candle form,

Once I get candle, need to get OHLC data of this candle,

How can I store this candle?

Answer (score 0):

The `var` keyword retains the value of a variable. You can use it like this:

```
var float o_open = na
var float o_high = na
var float o_low = na
var float o_close = na

if your_condition
    o_open := open
    o_high := high
    o_low := low
    o_close := close
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried to add diff like below, but it throw compilation error,

```var float diff = o_high - o_low

hline(diff, "+50",  color.lime)```

Comment: You can’t use a series with `hline()` function. You can use `line.new()` function instead